# What is the default source list of Kali Linux 2.0?

Tags: kali-linux

I edited my Kali Linux 2.0 source list and I forgot the default.
What's the default source list and what does it look like?

Comment: Just a bit of googling won't help?

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the [Kali documentation](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories). For Kali 2.0 (sana), you need

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

For access to sources packages, you also need

```
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Thanks, is it okay if I add the Kali rolling and kali moto reps.?

Comment: No, it is not okay, you should only have the repository entries for a single release (unless you really know what you're doing). If you're using 2.0, use the 2.0 entries; if you want to upgrade to Rolling, then do a proper upgrade (check the documentation).